# How can I replace generators if I need only one result?

Tags: haskell, generator

I'm playing with Haskell for first time.

I've created function that returns first precise enough result. It works as expected, but I'm using generator for this. How can I replace generator in this task?

```
integrateWithPrecision precision =
    (take 1 $ preciseIntegrals precision) !! 0

preciseIntegrals :: Double -> [Double]
preciseIntegrals precision =
    [
        integrate (2 ^ power) pi | power <- [0..],
        enoughPowerForPrecision power precision
    ]
```

Comment: What do you want to replace it with and why? I don't really see the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Trapezoidal rule integration. I need first precise enough result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to check higher and higher powers until you get one that satisfies a requirement. This is what you could do: First you define a function to get enough power, and then you integrate using that.

`find` gets the first element of a list that satisfies a condition – like being enough of a  power! Then we need a `fromJust` to get the actual value from that. Please note that almost always, `fromJust` is a *terrible* idea to have in your code. However, in this case the list is infinite, so we will have troubles with infinite loops long before `fromJust` is able to crash the program.

```
enoughPower :: Double -> Int
enoughPower precision =
  fromJust $ find (flip enoughPowerForPrecision precision) [0..]

preciseIntegrals :: Double -> Double
preciseIntegrals precision = integrate (2^(enoughPower precision)) pi
```

Comment: Thanks, `find` is very useful abstraction and I can understand why `fromJust` is a bad idea.

Comment: You can find `find` in `Data.List`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the beautiful `until` function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html#until).  Here it is:

```
-- | @'until' p f@ yields the result of applying @f@ until @p@ holds.
until                   :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
until p f x | p x       =  x
            | otherwise =  until p f (f x)
```

So, you can write your function like this:

```
integrateWithPrecision precision = integrate (2 ^ pow) pi
  where
    pow = until done succ 0
    done pow = enoughPowerForPrecision pow precision
```

In your case, you do all the iteration and then compute a result just once.  But `until` is useful even when you need to compute a result at each step - just use an `(iter, result)` tuple and then just extract the `result` at the end with `snd`.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
\xs -> take 1 xs !! 0
```

is called `head`

```
head []     = error "Cannot take head of empty list"
head (x:xs) = x
```

Its use is somewhat unsafe, as shown it can throw an error if you pass it an empty list, but in this case since you can be certain your list is non-empty it's fine.

---

Also, we tend not to call these "generators" in Haskell as they're not a special form but are instead a simple consequence of lazy evaluation. In this case, `preciseIntegrals` is called a "list comprehension" and `[0..]` is nothing more than a lazily generated list.

Comment: Thanks for `head` and `comprehensions`. Is there any function in haskell to replace this `comprehension`? My main experience is Java/JS/PHP, maybe that's why I try to avoid using lists where possible.

Comment: @Devgru You can replace your comprehension with `map` and `filter`, but you will not gain any additional power from that – it is simply a stylistic choice. It's not clear why you would want to do that replacement.